# how to handle unknownhost exception in netsuite

Tags: java, netsuite

i'm doing java app integration with ns.sometimes i'm getting Unknown host exception.i want to handle this exception how to do this one....while i'm getting this exception ,restarting my server again.below is the stack trace...

```
09:46:10,927 ERROR [STDERR] AxisFault

09:46:10,928 ERROR [STDERR] faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException

09:46:10,928 ERROR [STDERR] faultSubcode: 

09:46:10,928 ERROR [STDERR] faultString: java.net.UnknownHostException: webservices.netsuite.com

09:46:10,932 ERROR [STDERR] faultActor: 

09:46:10,932 ERROR [STDERR] faultNode: 

09:46:10,933 ERROR [STDERR] faultDetail: 

09:46:10,933 ERROR [STDERR] {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.UnknownHostException: webservices.netsuite.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting UnknownHostException, that means you are not connecting to the right URL. Netsuite webservice is hosted at

"https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2013_2" for production environment AND "https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2013_2" for sandbox environment.